# Can a Raspberry Pi GPU be used with Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, linux

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 and a 3, both of which have separate GPUs from the CPU. They are running the default Raspbian (9 I think), and Blender (slightly out-of-daste repository version) is successfully installed. Can I configure Cycles to work with the GPU or vice versa, possibly with additional software installation?

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77574/blender-build-for-raspberry-pi3

Comment: In addition to what @cegaton linked, OpenCL is kinda supported on the RPi with https://github.com/doe300/VC4CL so it might be possible, depending on the limitations of the embedded profile. Its pretty likely that this would require a lot of mucking around with custom blender builds.